# Simple WPF IValueConverter and DataTrigger not working together

Tags: wpf, datatrigger, ivalueconverter

I've been having trouble using a value converter with a data trigger. In some of my code it seems like the `DataTrigger`'s `Path` is being applied to the root element, rather than the element which the style applies to.

I created a simple test case, and I don't understand its behavior. I'm expecting the `Button` to turn red or blue depending on which value is being fed to the `DataTrigger`'s converter, but the `Button` isn't being affected at all!

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimpleWpfApplication"
    x:Class="SimpleWpfApplication.SimpleUserControl"
    ToolTip="UserControl ToolTip">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:SimpleConverter x:Key="SimpleConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Button ToolTip="Button ToolTip">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding Path=ToolTip, Converter={StaticResource SimpleConverter}}"
                        Value="Button ToolTip">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding Path=ToolTip, Converter={StaticResource SimpleConverter}}"
                        Value="UserControl ToolTip">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

And a simple converter:

```
class SimpleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("SimpleConverter is a OneWay converter.");
    }
}
```

Why isn't `Convert` being called? Why doesn't the `Button` turn red or blue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer in another StackOverflow question: [What’s wrong with my datatrigger binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728159/whats-wrong-with-my-datatrigger-binding)

The answer is to add `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` to the binding:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ToolTip,
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                       Converter={StaticResource SimpleConverter}}" />
```